# Comparação de igualdade

Tags: advpl, clipper, harbour

Estou estudando ADVPL e me deparei com duas formas de fazer a comparação de igualdade.

Existem comparações feitas com dois sinais de igual:

```
if cVar == "Valor"
endif
```

Mas também existem alguns poucos casos que encontrei, que essa comparação é feita com apenas um sinal de igual:

```
if cVar = "Valor"
endif
```

Existe diferença nessas duas formas de efetuar uma comparação de igualdade?

Comment: Em dialetos xbase usar `=` é uma armadilha, pois tanto pode ser atribuição quanto comparação (sem o if em vez de um erro de sintaxe vai ocorrer o equivalente a `cVar := valor`, e isso vai passar despercebido dependendo do contexto). Como disse o @Maniero, melhor `:=` ou `==`. Eu até configurei meu editor pra mostrar o `=` sozinho com fundo vermelho pra não ter perigo, eu uso Harbour bastante no dia a dia. (Caso não conheça, Harbour seria mais ou menos como o ADVPL em sintaxe, mas implementado de uma maneira bem sólida, para uso geral e multiplataforma, com retrocompatibilidade com Clipper)

Comment: Obrigado, nem sabia que era possível fazer a atribuição de valor assim, sempre fui ensinado a fazer com :=

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A primeira forma é a mais correta para quase todos os casos. Eu até ignoraria a segunda. Pode parecer que é útil, mas é melhor usar uma forma mais explícita quando precisa dessa semântica.

A segunda forma não compara a igualdade perfeita em textos, compara apenas uma parte do texto ignorando os caracteres excedentes do primeiro, ou seja, ele compara a quantidade de caracteres que o texto da direita do operador tiver, ele não olha para o que vem depois dessa quantidade no primeiro texto, então no exemplo abaixo o `x` será ignorado e será considerado igual quando usa o `=`.

```
"Valorx" = "Valor"
"Valor" == "Valor"
"Valorx" != "Valor"
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/xBase/ADVPLEqualSignOperators.prg).

Se ligar o `set exact on` aí o `=` fica igual ao `==`. Mas pode garantir que em todo código ele está ligado? Nem sempre a pessoa pode. Aconselho ligar, mesmo assim não use esse operador.

Um dos problemas é que é fácil se enganar nisso. Geralmente não é o que deseja.

Para outros tipos não muda em relação à `==`.

Digo mais, quando for atribuir um valor para a variável sempre use `:=` e não apenas `=` que funciona, mas confunde o operador de atribuição com o de comparação parcial. Para todos os efeitos ignore o `=`, seja para atribuir ou para comparar, use só `:=` e `==` respectivamente.

Isso é um defeito de sintaxe herdado do dBase.

[Documentação](https://harbour.github.io/doc/clc53.html#eq-equality-op).

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a resposta do @Maniero, ao utilizar a função `aScan` que busca valores no array, a comparação de igualdade é feita somente com um sinal de igual, logo ao fazer um aScan da seguinte forma:

```
aScan(aMeuArray, "Valor")
```

Ele pode acabar encontrando a posição do array e você ter um falso positivo.

Para buscar strings em array, normalmente declaramos o bloco de código, que permite fazer a verificação de igualdade com os dois sinais de igual:

```
aScan(aMeuArray, {|cValorPosicaoArray| cValorPosicaoArray == "Valor"})
```

---

Exemplo:

```
function u_Testing()
local aMeuArray as array
local nPosicao as numeric

aMeuArray := {"Valor "}

nPosicao := aScan(aMeuArray, "Valor")

//Encontrou o item no array
ConOut("Posicao encontrada:", nPosicao)

nPosicao := aScan(aMeuArray, {|cValorPosicaoArray| cValorPosicaoArray == "Valor"})

//Não encontrou o item no array
ConOut("Posicao encontrada:", nPosicao)

return
```

Comment: Creio que se o ADVPL respeitou o Clipper, o "set exact" define se a comparação vai ser exata ou não no `ASCan()` também. Valeria um teste com `SET EXACT ON` e `SET EXACT OFF`

Comment: Sim, o comportamento do ```aScan``` também é alterado conforme o ```set exact```  :D